# Angular 4 update array from service and in the view

Tags: angular, service, observable

I have a service that fetches data from API. And I have a component which use this service.

Once the data comes it stores array of messages in messages[] variable. Then in the view I do ngFor loop to loop through the objects and display the data. It all works fine, but I hove another function, which triggered when user click on the button, this function use the same service but passes different parameters so returns different result so then it should update the messages[] variable and update the view.

But the problem the app crashes and I don't know why, it does not update the message[]. So how to update the same variable when function called and show the changes in the view?

this is my service:

```
//returns all messages from API passing pagenumber and how many results to return
getAllMessages(page: number, numberOfRows: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('/api/messages?offset=' + page + '&batchsize=' + numberOfRows).map(data => data)
}
```

so in my component:

```
   messages: any[];

    ngOnInit() {

       setDefaultPageLoad(pageOffset: number) {
    this.messageService.getAllMessages(pageOffset, 25).subscribe(data => {
       this.messages = data.messages,

    }

         }
      otherFunction(){
          this.messageService.getAllMessages(pageOffset, 12).subscribe(data => {
       this.messages = data.messages,

       }

    })
```

And the view

```
<button (click)="otherFunction()">Update<button> //Once clicked should update
   <div *ngFor="let message of messages">
     {{message.name}}
   </div>
```

Comment: there is issue with the function

Comment: And what is the issue ? you provided no error ...

Comment: chrome just freeze it seems like to loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing **`"`** in **`ngFor`**

```
 <div *ngFor="let message of messages">
     {{message.name}}
   </div>
```

also function should have paranthesis()

```
(click)="otherFunction()"
```

Comment: (click)="otherFunction()" it should be